# An undirected graph is a tree iff there is exactly one simple path between each pair of vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The problem is as written in the title, I give the official proof as I was given and then my question afterwards:

**Official Answer**:
$ ( \leftarrow ) $ Suppose that there is a single simple path between every two vertices. Suppose G is not a tree ( we'll contradict this ), hence it has a circuit and hence it has a simple circuit:
[image]
In this circuit there are at-least 3 vertices ( we are talking about undirected graph ). Then between $ v_1 $ and $ v_2 $ there are two simple different paths:
[image]
Hence we got that we have two different simple paths between $ v_1 $ and $ v_2 $ - Contradiction.
( $ \rightarrow $ ) Now suppose that G is a tree. Specifically, G is connected and hence there exists a simple path between every two vertices. Suppose ( we'll contradict this ) there are two vertices $v,u$ with at-least two simple and different paths between them and we'll take two such paths with a *minimal* distance from all the paths from $ u $ to $ v $. We'll look at two simple paths between $ v,u $ s.t. one of them is a shortest simple path.

**Claim**: every two paths are disjoint ( different ) in their vertices ( besides $ v,u$ )
       **Proof of claim:**  Suppose ( we'll contradict this ) that the paths aren't disjoint. Then there exists a common vertex $ w $, since the paths are different we deduce one of the following occurs:
There exist two different and simple paths between $v,w $.
There exist two different and simple paths between $w,u $.
In both cases we'll get a contradiction for  assumption that the distance between $ v $ and $ u $ was minimal.  $ \square $

We got then that the paths are disjoint in their vertices, hence in the circuit that we get from chaining the two paths there is no repitition on the vertices ( besides the first and last ). In addition, there are at-least 3 vertices in this circuit ( since the paths are different ), hence the circuit is simple. From here we get a contradiction to the assumption that $ G $ is a tree.
[image]

$ \square $

**My question:**
I didn't really understand The proof of the **claim**, how did they get a contradiction for the assumption that the distance between $v$ and $u $ was minimal? I don't really understand that. ( I understand though that there might exist 2 different paths between $ u ,v$ where $w $ is common vertex. I drew a picture to help me see it: )
[image]

**Note**: I know there are answers here on how to prove this theorem, but my question is not about that, it is about the claim above in the proof

Comment: I think the assumption that you are trying to contradict is not the right one. The assumption should be : "Consider all the pairs of different simple paths having the same extremities. Among all the paths belonging to these pairs, choose $l$ whose length is minimal. Then among all the pairs $\{l, l'\}$ containing it, choose one such that $l'$ is of minimal length (among such $l'$). Let $u$, $v$ be the extremities of $l$ (and $l'$)." Etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that the second part is needed (maybe it is enough to choose any $l'$), but that is the idea : you should take a minimum among all possible extremities, not among the paths between two fixed vertices.

Comment: So I choose a path $l $ with minimal length where $ u, v$ are its extremities. Then I'm looking at all other paths $ l' $ where $ u,v $ are its extremities and I'm choosing the path $ l' $ whose length is also minimal but different from path $ l $?

Comment: The cause of confusion seems to be the formulation in the proof, which is ambiguous : it is not clear where the $u$, $v$ used in the sequel are defined. I think the idea is what I describe (which is the idea that works), but the way it is written down is very misleading.

Comment: You need to choose the (simple) path $l$ minimal among those for which there is another (simple) path with the same extremities. Then you say that $u$ and $v$ are its extremities. And you choose $l'$ another simple path between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: You can choose $l'$ to be minimal among the possible choices (once $l$ is fixed), but I think you can get a contradiction without this assumption

Comment: I'll think about it, I find the proof very confusing for me, unfortunately I couldn't find another proof of the theorem which is as elaborate as the one above. I'll sleep over it and understand it better.

Comment: The important thing is : $l$ exists because we suppose that there is at least one pair of paths with the same extremities (this is the assertion that we want to contradict). And then $l'$ exists by definition of $l$